# Time complexity of std::vector::erase on the beginning element of a vector

Tags: c++11, vector, runtime, time-complexity

After taking a look at how vector.erase works I am unsure if the run time complexity of std::vector::erase on the first element of a vector. Would it be constant time?

Comment: According to [this `erase` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) it's linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [[vector.modifiers]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.modifiers) (emphasis mine):

> iterator erase(const_iterator position);
>     iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
>
> [...]
>
> Complexity: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to the number of the elements erased, but **the assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector after the erased elements**.

Hence, when you erase the first element, you get one destructor call and `size() - 1` assignments, which is linear time complexity.